# Como utilizar a classe TIMER em um metodo com Math.max e Math.min

Tags: java, swing, timer

Estou com um projeto meio ambicioso de criar meu joguinho de matemática (o qual achei melhor que uma simples calculadora) em apenas um `JFrame`, somente com métodos, sem usar nenhuma outra classe no pacote...

Com a ajuda do `Swing` e do GUI `builder` do Netbeans

Certo dia, ouvi falar da classe `Timer`, contudo, não encontro nada sobre utilizar ele dentro de um método, somente dentro de outra classe sem o `main`

Eu tentei utilizar ele em um método numa pergunta que fiz a um certo tempo, infelizmente, acabei perdendo o código (pois não funcionou)

Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo de como seria a utilização dessa classe num método? (de preferência, num temporizador decrescente)

Comment: Um exemplo da aplicação da classe Timer? Seria interessante você editar, citando uma situação mais especifica para o uso, pra que a pergunta não fique ampla, já que pode ser inumeros os exemplos usando essa classe.

Comment: ok @DiegoF, editei com poucas palavras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `TimerTask` e `Timer`do `java.util` Segue um exemplo:

```
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ExemploTimer  extends TimerTask {

    private int numeroExecucao = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        numeroExecucao++;
        System.out.println("Exemplo Timer executando: " + numeroExecucao);
        //Aqui você executa as suas ações da thead.
    }

}
```

**EXECUTANDO SUA CLASSE**

```
public class ExemploMain {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Em qualquer lugar você pode utilizar a sua classe.

        ExemploTimer exemploTimer = new ExemploTimer();


        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        //data atual + 10 minutos.
        Date dataPrimeiraExecucao = new Date();
        //Tempo para execução, executar a cada 10 segundos
        long tempoParaProximaExecucao = 1000 * 10; 
        // Shedule, acredito que isto é o que você precisa
        timer.schedule(exemploTimer, dataPrimeiraExecucao, tempoParaProximaExecucao);

        //Este código serve apenas para esperar a linha acima executar.
        //Deve ser eliminado no seu código.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ExemploMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Para complementar segue alguns exemplos e tutoriais:

[Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

[Timer Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044729/java-timer-task-schedule)

Comment: E isso não da problema com swing, já que este possui thread propria? talvez seria interessante usar o Timer da api swing para GUI.

Comment: @DiegoF tem o **SwingWorker** que pode ser utilizado para não travar os componentes **Swing**, mas este exemplo que coloquei cria uma tarefa que deve ser executada em um período de tempo, utilizo com Swing também e não trava os componentes.

Comment: @ElyelRubensdaRosa vou tentar, mas seria melhor se eu conseguisse fazer algo no `Java` sem ter que criar um bilhão de classes dentro de trilhões de pacotes, por que usar somente a classe que contem o método `main` fica bem mais fácil ;-;

Comment: @FabricioCardoso Esta pode ser a sua visão no momento, mas acredite, você pode organizar muito bem o seu projeto com pacotes e classes de forma que fique muito fácil de você trabalhar, o ideal é que o método main seja o mais enxuto possível, chamando as funções principais do seu jogo. Quando você chegar na metade do caminho pode ser tarde para considerar estas coisas. De qualquer forma, caso queira fazer tudo em um só lugar, recomendo utilizar o exemplo que passei e escrever toda a sua lógica dentro do método run.

Comment: @ElyelRubensdaRosa  Ok... eu desisto, eu vim do C pro JAVA, dai, ainda prefiro fazer tudo em 1 só lugar, mas vou tentar separar meus métodos em outras classes
ao meu ver, ainda é bem melhor assim, com o tempo eu aprendo hehehe

Comment: @FabricioCardoso É complicado começar uma mudança de hábitos, mas quanto acostuma você verá muitas vantagens. Caso tenha dúvidas de como estruturar o início, coloca o seu problema ai que podemos te ajudar.

Comment: @ElyelRubensdaRosa Realmente... mas, não esta sendo tão difícil fazer algo somente com uma classe que contem o `main`, bom, ate o momento, não precisei de quase nada dentro do `main`, somente dos métodos, já que estou usando o `GUI Builder` do NetBeans para o swing, então facilita tentar algo legal.
Mas eu vou tentar me habituar a este estilo novo de ter um zilhao de pacotes com classes diferentes para apenas uma aplicação. 
Qualquer duvida além, eu posto o código aqui e peço ajuda novamente ^^